# Webinars in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, webinar

I want to build a webinar application in wordpress. I also wanted to integrate woocommerce with it. I used a plugin called webinarpress. But some of its features, like woocommerce integration is available only in paid option. Does any one know free plugins for integrating webinars and woocommerce together on wordpress site.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plugin is also good for webinar system

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-gotowebinar/

Comment: Hi Neal Developer, thanks for the solution. I've seen https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-gotowebinar/ plugin too. It is also paid for woocommerce. I need a system where webinars are created as products, and webinar link should be sent to a mail which is given during checkout.

Comment: Can check WPWebinarSystem plugin https://www.wpwebinarsystem.com/